# Any book or tutorial about good practices or typical mistakes when conducting scientific research?

Tags: research-process, books

Some days ago I read this question:
[Feynman describing a scientific error](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/8961/feynman-and-scientific-method)
and I found it quite interesting. Although it seems naïve it could be a typical mistake made by a beginner researcher as me.

My question is that if anyone knows a book or tutorial that explains the typical mistakes or some advices when conducting research (theoretical or experimental). By the way, I am not asking for advices such as the ones described in
[Good research practices](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/2953/advice-on-good-research-practices)
even though they are also useful they are generic tips and do not describe the common errors done when doing research.

Thanks!

Comment: Such a thick book, that would be!

Answer (score 1):

Thomas Kuhn's "The structure of scientific revolutions." A fantastic introduction about how advances in science are usually made.

Answer (score 0):

I think that a good place to start would be [What Is This Thing Called Science?](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/What_Is_This_Thing_Called_Science%3F) by Alan Chalmers.

This will give you an overview of the disputed concept of the scientific process. It will explain how researchers have continually evolved their views as to what is acceptable scientific practice, and as part of this, what general scientific practices seem most reasonable to adopt in different circumstances. It will also make you wary of assuming that there are always universally accepted, or applicable, rules for good science.